# Connect to Redis service from different service using kubernetes

Tags: go, redis, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes Cluster on google cloud platform with a number of services deployed. I imported redis-go in my compute service and can create a new client here to store/retrieve data to my redis service. I want to be able to access this stored data from a different service also. I tried using redis-go and creating a new client with the same address to my redis service cluster but I can't retrieve any of the data. So basically I am wondering how I can connect to a single redis-service instance from multiple services. Here is an example of code I am using to Dial my redis-service and store/retrieve value. I can store and retrieve from each individual service but if I store from one service and try retrieve from another it does not work.

```
      conn, _ := redis.Dial("tcp", "redis:6379")
      defer conn.Close()


      conn.Do("SET", "bbcTrump", "someValue")
    //someValue, _:= conn.Do("GET", "bbcTrump")
```

In addition here is my redis-deployment.yaml and redis-service.yaml code. Maybe there is a problem here.

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.10.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: redis
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: redis
        name: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        resources: {}

      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.10.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: redis
  name: redis
spec:
  ports:
   - port: 6379
     targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: redis
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: _but I can't retrieve any of the data_ Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rephrase your question as "when I tried $foo, it did $bar, with error $err, but I was expecting $baz"

Comment: There are no errors. I just want to know how you can connect to the same redis service from other services in GKE. I explained that I created a new client with redis-go in my compute-service and can store and retrieve data to my redis-service. However, when I tried creating the same kind of client in a different service I can't retrieve any data that was set in the compute service. So that leads me to the actual question at the end of my OP, how can I connect to a single redis-service instance from multiple services.

Comment: _I can't retrieve any data that was set in the compute service_ again, I wish I knew how to explain in simpler words: how do you know you are not retrieving any data: some error, zero keys found, times out, ... other? if you `redis-cli MONITOR` from within one of the `redis` Pods, do you see other keys arriving -- that is, do you know for sure the other operation is actually correctly setting the keys to make them available for read?

Comment: And do you still have `replicas: 1` as shown in the descriptor? because redis does not cluster itself automatically: one must take explicit steps to cluster them, otherwise k8s will round-robin across connections to the `Service`, which would also do weird things

Comment: I am getting "nil" when I try read the data from a different service. I can write and read from a single service so I know those functions are working. My understanding of having a single replica is that there is one redis service not multiples. Meaning the data I am sending to my redis service should be retrievable from calls in other services. I could be very wrong here though so will see what the steps are for clustering. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I decided to use an intermediary service to handle all requests from other services. Not ideal but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I set the image pull policy in my compute-service deployment yaml to always. I also changed its port to :8080 and upgraded my GCP from a trial. One of these or a combination fixed the issue.